# building XML in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, builder

Using many help articles and cases from SO and codehaus i wrote something like this:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
def EUIDroster = context.expand(here goes some data like '[123000,123001]' )

def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

builder() {
    EUIDList(){
        for (e in EUIDroster){EUID(e)}
    }
}

EUIDList.println()
```

my goal is to make an xml file with structure like:

```
<EUID>123001</EUID>
<EUID>123002</EUID>
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def EUIDroster = [123000,123001]
def writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder( writer ).EUIDList {
    EUIDroster.each { e ->
        EUID( e )
    }
}
println writer.toString()
```

That should print:

```
<EUIDList>
  <EUID>123000</EUID>
  <EUID>123001</EUID>
</EUIDList>
```

Comment: it works, but i got some troubles with soapUI, but code is 100% works! Thank you!

Comment: it divides xml tags like this:     <EUID>1</EUID> <EUID>2</EUID> instead of <EUID>12</EUID>

Comment: @EugeneUvarovAudiogenetic What is `EUIDroster`? A String?  Or a List?

Comment: EUIDRoster is a string

Comment: @EugeneUvarovAudiogenetic A string representation of a list?  ie: `"['12','13']"` as in your question, or a String like `"12"`?

Comment: it goes like `"[12, 13]"`

Comment: @EugeneUvarovAudiogenetic Yeah, so it's a String? ie: `assert EUIDroster == "[12, 13]"` passes?